# ¿Algo Mal aqui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

realize este Script  pero no envia o recibe alguna variable, alguien me ingica si es error de sintaxis? Estoy usando JavaScript, Ajax y jquery

```
function insertedf(){
    var Typo_1 = document.getElementById('surmit').value;
    var Mes_var = document.getElementById('MesIDs').value;
    var ID_Scala_var = document.getElementById('ID_ScalaIDs').value;
    var Pt_Req_var = document.getElementById('Pt_ReqIDs').value;
    var ItemID_1_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_1IDs').value;
    var ItemID_2_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_2IDs').value;
    var ItemID_3_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_3IDs').value;
    var ItemID_4_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_4IDs').value;
    var ItemID_5_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_5IDs').value;
    var ItemID_6_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_6IDs').value;
    var ItemID_7_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_7IDs').value;
    var ItemID_8_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_8IDs').value;
    var ItemID_9_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_9IDs').value;
    var ItemID_10_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_10IDs').value;
    var Cantid_1_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_1IDs').value;
    var Cantid_2_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_2IDs').value;
    var Cantid_3_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_3IDs').value;
    var Cantid_4_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_4IDs').value;
    var Cantid_5_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_5IDs').value;
    var Cantid_6_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_6IDs').value;
    var Cantid_7_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_7IDs').value;
    var Cantid_8_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_8IDs').value;
    var Cantid_9_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_9IDs').value;
    var Cantid_10_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_10IDs').value;
    var parametrs_1 = {
        'surmit' : Typo_1,
        'Mes' : Mes_var,
        'ID_Scala' : ID_Scala_var,
        'Pt_Req' : Pt_Req_var,
        'ItemID_1' : ItemID_1_var,
        'ItemID_2' : ItemID_2_var,
        'ItemID_3' : ItemID_3_var,
        'ItemID_4' : ItemID_4_var,
        'ItemID_5' : ItemID_5_var,
        'ItemID_6' : ItemID_6_var,
        'ItemID_7' : ItemID_7_var,
        'ItemID_8' : ItemID_8_var,
        'ItemID_9' : ItemID_9_var,
        'ItemID_10' : ItemID_10_var,
        'Cantid_1' : Cantid_1_var,
        'Cantid_2' : Cantid_2_var,
        'Cantid_3' : Cantid_3_var,
        'Cantid_4' : Cantid_4_var,
        'Cantid_5' : Cantid_5_var,
        'Cantid_6' : Cantid_6_var,
        'Cantid_7' : Cantid_7_var,
        'Cantid_8' : Cantid_8_var,
        'Cantid_9' : Cantid_9_var,
        'Cantid_10' : Cantid_10_var
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: parametrs_1,
        url: './functions/scal_inserted.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            $('#precioens').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Seria bueno ver parte de tu `html` porque al parecer estas utilizando malas practicas.

Comment: Lo otro es que creo que no puedes enviar un objeto de javascript directamente sin especificarle primero a `jQuery` que lo vas a hacer, deberias poner un metodo mas, el metodo `fail` para imprimir el error dentro.

Comment: si lo simplifico me va bien, en html los identifi con  id, y name y values he hecho varios pero este me esta comiendo y quiero adelanta ese trozo gracias

Comment: como seria metodo fail? me enseñas por favor?

Comment: Esta pagina lo muestra `https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/` alli dice el metodo y donde debe usarse, pero en resumen es exactamente igual que `success` solo cambia el `success`.

Comment: como asi? como seaia eso me lo muestras por favor?

Comment: @Riven el parámetro para indicar a jQuery que quieres mandar datos en la petición Ajax es `data`, mientras que `fail` es para controlar los posibles errores. Pero OJO: `fail` se usa con `done` (una versión de `success` basada en promesas), si usas `success` la función de captura de errores se llama `error`  no `fail`. Juan Carlos, si cuando lo simplificas funciona, significa entonces que está fallando al recuperar alguno de los elementos. Revisa la consola, allí deberás ver el error. Si fuera tú simplificaría la captura de parámetros,  ...

Comment: ... poniendo los datos en un formulario o construyendo el objeto de forma dinámica con un selector o algo así. De ese modo evitarías declarar todas esas variables a mano, reduciendo código y minimizando posibles errores.

Comment: Ah ok, solo un detalle, creo que si la persona sabe no estuviera preguntando aqui no se pero me da como duda. crees que si supiera preguntara? creo este sitio fue hecho amigo para responder dudas y ayudar a la comunidad de programadores no para hacer adivinanzas o investigacion para eso existen manuales amigo, la verda discupa sigo sin entender y no veo su respuesta por ningun lado eso que usted "indica" no ayuda en NADA

Comment: solo a dar mas interrogantes que ayudas, buscare en un foro (DE INVESTIGACION) ayuda sobre **fail** para javascript.

Comment: gracias igualmente muy amable usted

Answer (score 0):

Sugiero cambiarle el nombre a las variables por nombres más entendibles.

Un ejemplo, le quité todo lo que diga `IDs`, `ID`, cambié `Item` por `i`, y `Cantid` por `c`.

```js
var x = `var Typo_1 = document.getElementById('surmit').value;
var Mes_var = document.getElementById('MesIDs').value;
var ID_Scala_var = document.getElementById('ID_ScalaIDs').value;
var Pt_Req_var = document.getElementById('Pt_ReqIDs').value;
var ItemID_1_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_1IDs').value;
var ItemID_2_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_2IDs').value;
var ItemID_3_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_3IDs').value;
var ItemID_4_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_4IDs').value;
var ItemID_5_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_5IDs').value;
var ItemID_6_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_6IDs').value;
var ItemID_7_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_7IDs').value;
var ItemID_8_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_8IDs').value;
var ItemID_9_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_9IDs').value;
var ItemID_10_var = document.getElementById('ItemID_10IDs').value;
var Cantid_1_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_1IDs').value;
var Cantid_2_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_2IDs').value;
var Cantid_3_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_3IDs').value;
var Cantid_4_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_4IDs').value;
var Cantid_5_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_5IDs').value;
var Cantid_6_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_6IDs').value;
var Cantid_7_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_7IDs').value;
var Cantid_8_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_8IDs').value;
var Cantid_9_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_9IDs').value;
var Cantid_10_var = document.getElementById('Cantid_10IDs').value;
`

console.log(
  x.match(/'.*'/g).map(x => x.slice(1, -1).replace(/(IDs|ID|_|Ite|Canti)/g, "").replace(/m/g, "i").replace(/d/g, "c")).join(" ")
)
```

De esta manera los nombres de las variables quedan así:

`suriit Mes Scala PtReq i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 i10 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10`

Genero los `input` desde estos nombres.

```js
function crear_elemento(e, atributo, x, nodo) {
  var e = document.createElement(e)
  atributo && (e[atributo] = x)
  nodo.appendChild(e)
  return e
}
var p = document.querySelector("p")

function generar_elementos(p, x) {
  var div = crear_elemento(
    "div", null, null, p
  )
  if (typeof x == "string") {
    crear_elemento(
      "a", "innerHTML", `${x}: `, div
    )
    crear_elemento(
      "input", "id", x, div
    )
  }else{
    crear_elemento(
      "a", "innerHTML", `Producto ${x} `, div
    )
    var a = crear_elemento(
      "input", "id", `i${x}`, div
    )
    crear_elemento(
      "a", "innerHTML", ` Cantidad `, div
    )
    var c = crear_elemento(
      "input", "id", `c${x}`, div
    )
    a.style.width = "100px"
    c.style.width = "50px"
  }
  p.innerHTML += "\n\n"
}

"suriit Mes Scala PtReq".split(" ").map(x => {
  generar_elementos(p, x)
})

var i = 0
var items = [...Array(10)].map(x => {
  generar_elementos(p, ++i)
})

crear_elemento(
  "textarea","value",p.innerHTML, p
)
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Entonces, los parámetros pueden obtenerse así... Se va obteniendo el resultado de los datos cuando se pulsa una tecla en el `input`.

```js
function obtener_datos() {
  var objeto = {}
  Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll("input")
  ).map(x => objeto[x.id] = x.value)
  return objeto
}

var datos = obtener_datos()
console.log(datos)

Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll("input")
).map(x => {
  x.addEventListener(
    "keyup", () => {
      window.datos = obtener_datos()
      console.log(window.datos)
    }
  )
})
```

```html
<div><a>suriit: </a><input id="suriit"></div>

<div><a>Mes: </a><input id="Mes"></div>

<div><a>Scala: </a><input id="Scala"></div>

<div><a>PtReq: </a><input id="PtReq"></div>

<div><a>Producto 1 </a><input id="i1" style="width: 100px;"><a> Cantidad </a><input id="c1" style="width: 50px;"></div>

<div><a>Producto 2 </a><input id="i2" style="width: 100px;"><a> Cantidad </a><input id="c2" style="width: 50px;"></div>

<div><a>Producto 3 </a><input id="i3" style="width: 100px;"><a> Cantidad </a><input id="c3" style="width: 50px;"></div>

<div><a>Producto 4 </a><input id="i4" style="width: 100px;"><a> Cantidad </a><input id="c4" style="width: 50px;"></div>

<div><a>Producto 5 </a><input id="i5" style="width: 100px;"><a> Cantidad </a><input id="c5" style="width: 50px;"></div>

<div><a>Producto 6 </a><input id="i6" style="width: 100px;"><a> Cantidad </a><input id="c6" style="width: 50px;"></div>

<div><a>Producto 7 </a><input id="i7" style="width: 100px;"><a> Cantidad </a><input id="c7" style="width: 50px;"></div>

<div><a>Producto 8 </a><input id="i8" style="width: 100px;"><a> Cantidad </a><input id="c8" style="width: 50px;"></div>

<div><a>Producto 9 </a><input id="i9" style="width: 100px;"><a> Cantidad </a><input id="c9" style="width: 50px;"></div>

<div><a>Producto 10 </a><input id="i10" style="width: 100px;"><a> Cantidad </a><input id="c10" style="width: 50px;"></div>
```

Para ver los datos recibidos desde PHP se usa `$_POST`

- Documentación de `$_POST`  https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php

Es necesario comprobar si el archivo que se está pidiendo existe... Se está usando una ruta relativa, quizás el problema sea ese.

```
url: './functions/scal_inserted.php',
```

Quitando el punto del principio quedaría ruta absoluta:

```
url: '/functions/scal_inserted.php',
```

Ejemplo de `$_POST` de *PHP*:

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

También es posible ver la respuesta desde las herramientas de desarrollador, solamente hay que presionar <kbd>F12</kbd> para abrirla, o click derecho en algún lado y luego la opción *inspeccionar elemento (en ingles es inspect)*, y por último ir a la sección de *red (en inglés, network)*.